# scorm 2004 4th - list of correct and incorrect questions?

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm-cloud-api

Guys, tell me, can SCORM 2004 give to the LMS at the end to show a list of correct and incorrect questions?
if so, which model is responsible for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions are called 'interactions' in the SCORM run-time data model.

The specific property that says whether a question response is correct or incorrect (or how correct the response is) is `cmi.interactions.n.result` (where `n` is the index of the interaction).

You might also want to look at `cmi.interactions.n.correct_responses.n.pattern`  and `cmi.interactions.n.student_response`.